# How to create 'sub' tables of contents for each section in a table of contents in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book, information-architecture, table-of-contents

I have a document with multiple sections that has a table of contents (TOC) at the beginning, which includes h1-h3 styles for the whole document.

I want to create a sub TOC for a single section that includes the h1-h3 styles in that section only.

In other words:

I want to create another level of contents within each existing contents section.

Is this possible without having to create new heading styles for the specific section?

**How can I create multiple contents tables within an existing contents table in InDesign?**

Answer (score 3):

If you break up the document and reassemble the parts as a Book, you can have one TOC for the book (turn on the "Include Book Documents" checkbox) and an individual TOC in any of the chapter documents (turn off "Include Book Documents").

The alternative would be to duplicate the paragraph styles in question and give them slightly different names, then use those for your secondary TOC. The duplicates would be "based on" your main styles, so would echo any changes made to them.

Comment: I had already gone with the alternate option but as I'm sharing the document as a template, having the extra styles may be confusing. I also thought about the book option but ruled it out for the same reasons. Its the first time I've found something that Word does better than InDesign....and I hate Word!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can!
You need to create a new paragraph style (let's say H-Section).
At the start of each section put a text box with the H-Section.

Create a table of Style that lists your entries H1, H2, H3 e H-Section. To the entry from H-Section set a Paragraph Style that makes the text start from "In Next Frame" (Keep Options - Start Paragraph).

When you create the TOC the Style set to H-Section will make the text jump to another frame. All you have to do is creating a threaded text frame in each section starting page.