# InDesign CC - Making a table of contents that spans a single section

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, table-of-contents

I want a book where each new chapter has a page which displays a ToC containing the headers within that chapter.

The problem I'm running into is that indesign generates the contents for the entire document and I haven't been able to find a way to limit it to a single section.

I know I can probably do it by making a book out of multiple documents, but the truth is that the publication is short enough that it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Hi Miguel, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions:

1) Generate your full-book TOC and copy-paste your text in chunks as needed. (I think this is the faster way.)

2) Create a set of otherwise identical styles for each chapter. So you have your Chapter Headers style, and then duplicate it multiple times to create CH1, CH2, CH3, etc. A lot more moving parts depending on how many chapters you have, but then you can use each different set of styles to create individual TOC lists.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-paste the same answer I gave [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/how-to-create-sub-tables-of-contents-for-each-section-in-a-table-of-contents-i/81820#81820)
– Of course H1, H2, H3 are your CH1, CH2, CH3.

> Of course you can! You need to create a new paragraph style (let's say
>   H-Section). At the start of each section put a text box with the
>   H-Section.
>
> Create a table of Style that lists your entries H1, H2, H3 e
>   H-Section. To the entry from H-Section set a Paragraph Style that
>   makes the text start from "In Next Frame" (Keep Options - Start
>   Paragraph).
>
> When you create the TOC the Style set to H-Section will make the text
>   jump to another frame. All you have to do is creating a threaded text
>   frame in each section starting page.